# GrayScale Images rendering to dark area when written using JAI / ImageIO

Tags: java, graphics, rendering, javax.imageio

Can anyone explain why this happens. I read an image and render it into an output writer. If it is a color file (or black and white), it renders fine. However, if the source image is grayscale, all I get is a black box.

Sample files available at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kyfsh5curobwxrw/AACfWr1NhX8lPUZpzVGWIPQia?dl=0

My pom plugin dependancy snippets follow.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

A test program. I understand that this bit of code in itself is really of no value, but in reality it is part of a larger suite of operations. This code represents my efforts to narrow down the issue to a small piece of code.

```
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GrayScaleImaging {
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

    //works
//        final File inputFile = new File("/home/vinayb/Downloads/page1_color.tif");
//        final File outputFile = new File("/home/vinayb/Downloads/page1_color_mod.tif");

    //doesn't work
    final File inputFile = new File("/home/vinayb/Downloads/page1_grayscale.tif");
    final File outputFile = new File("/home/vinayb/Downloads/page1_grayscale_mod.tif");
    if (outputFile.exists()) {
        outputFile.delete();
    }

    ImageReader imageReader = null;
    ImageWriter imageWriter = null;
    Graphics2D g = null;

    try (final ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inputFile);
         final ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFile);) {


        //setup reader
        imageReader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageInputStream).next();
        imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);

        //read image
        final BufferedImage initialImage = imageReader.read(0);

        //prepare graphics for the output
        final BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(initialImage.getWidth(), initialImage.getHeight(), imageType(initialImage));
        g = finalImage.createGraphics();

        //do something to the image
        //doSomething(g)

        //draw image
        g.drawImage(initialImage, 0, 0, initialImage.getWidth(), initialImage.getHeight(), null);

        //setup writer based on reader
        imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWriter(imageReader);
        imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);

        //write
        imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(initialImage, null, imageReader.getImageMetadata(0)), imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam());
    } finally {
        //cleanup

        if (imageWriter != null) {
            imageWriter.dispose();
        }

        if (imageReader != null) {
            imageReader.dispose();
        }

        if (g != null) {
            g.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private static int imageType(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    return bufferedImage.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : bufferedImage.getType();
}
}
```

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: Why are you drawing the image onto itself? This is probably not your intention...

Comment: This is just a working snippet of code. In my actual application, I redact (add black rectangles over text), resize etc the graphics before drawing it back. That said, is there something else I should be doing ? Thanks

Comment: Does my comment make sense, or is there something else obvious that I am missing? Thx

Comment: No, it makes sense. But I'd still remove that code and see if it changes anything and if not, edit the question. Help your helpers focus on your problem, rather than non-issues. :-) Also, as TIFF reading/writing is not bundled with the JRE, you should probably mention what plugin you are using and what version etc. (I'd guess JAI but I may be wrong).

Comment: Hi, I changed the code a bit (as recommend) with no luck and spec'd the plugin version . Hopefully, the question is a bit clearer now

Comment: Minor update. I tried some other random grayscale tifs I downloaded as well as generated via [http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-tiff](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-tiff) and also uncompressed grayscale tiffs and they seem to work. Not sure what exactly the issue is with  the grayscale tif under test .

Comment: @VinayB: I think the problem is with your sample file. Dropbox was able to show it somehow, but after download, OS X Preview displayed it as completely black... My own TIFF reader throws an exception trying to decode it. Could be fixable, but I would have to research some more.

Comment: ...also, your "grayscale# sample file has `PhotometricInterpretation` 3, which means it is indexed color (palette), not really a grayscale image. It contains a 256 color `ColorMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have now fixed my decoder, thanks for the sample file! :-)

Anyway, after some research, I have come to the conclusion that the problem is definitively the sample file, not your code nor the library you are using.

The issue with this file is that the TIFF metadata contains `PhotometricInterpretation == 3`/Palette and `ColorMap` tags. Ie. the image uses indexed color model/palette. If the image is read as it should according to (my understanding of) the spec, using the supplied color map, the image comes out all black. If instead I ignore this, and rather read it as gray scale (assuming `PhotometricInterpretation == 1`/BlackIsZero), it comes out as black text on white (light gray) background.

Edit:

A better explanation, is that the values in the color map are all 8 bit quantities (using the low 8 bits of each color entry) instead of using the full 16 bit as they should... If I detect this while reading and creating a palette using only the low 8 bits, the image comes out as intended (as in DropBox). This is still a bad image according to the spec, but detectable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the research. I'll look into how the original image is created (by a third party library we use) . Apart from that, is there anything I can do to address the issue with the standard java / imageio libraries (I'm guessing not).

Comment: I Wonder if I intercept and modify PhotometricInterpretation in the metadata

Comment: @VinayB You could. But the image won't be accurate, other images may be completely off. I'd say your best bets would be either 1: Work around by telling the 3rd party lib to write grayscale instead of palette. 2: Fix the 3rd party lib. 3: Intercept and multiply all values in the colormap by 256. Or use my library, which now supports this, thanks to your question. :-)